# VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using my builtin laptop webcam on Ubuntu 12.04

It was working fine at the beginning but now it gives me constant errors

CODE:

```
using namespace cv;
/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

/// Read Video

VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges",1);
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}

cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it works again when I restart the computer, but just for one time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 . "VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument" error appeared while working with OpenCv version 2.4.8. I upgraded to OpenCv version 2.4.10 and error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and cannot be resolved even after installing opencv 2.4.10 .Issue got  resolved after installing libqt4-dev.
Here is the command:

sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to this issue: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3554